# Spring Roo - How to use it without AspectJ?

Tags: spring, configuration, aspectj, spring-roo, pojo

Is there a way to have Roo generate *real* POJOs and not AspectJ enhanced ones?

I want more PO in my JOs, AJ make it look like POJOOS (POJOs on Steroids) to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think Roo always creates projects using aspectj. However, you can do a "push in refactor" from eclipse or Spring Tool Suite (which removes aspectj as well as roo project support) as describe [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/removing.html).

Comment: In addition to the usage of Spring Security, I think this is a reason why Roo can't be popular.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is no. AspectJ inter-type declarations (ITD) are core to the Roo approach.